# High-side current sensing questions: Gain formula and circuit type

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, high-side

What is the formula for the gain in this circuit? I can not find a good description of the operation of this high-side current measurement. Why is there a PNP transistor at the output? What is the name of this configuration?

This is the circuit from the [datasheet of the bq500211](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq500211.pdf):

[image: High Side current]

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-monitor-current-with-an-op-amp-a-bjt-and-three-resistors/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if the circuit has a specific name but it sure is a type of current-to-current converter/amplifier: Generates a current proportional to the current-to-be-measured. This allows the designer to use a burden resistor to convert this current into a voltage for measurement purposes such as feeding to an ADC or using a ref voltage in a comparator.

Basically, the circuit utilizes the properties of a closed-loop operational amplifier:

- The inputs of the op amp are at equal voltage. In other words, the differential input voltage is zero.
- The inputs don't draw current.

[image]

Normally, **R17** can be omitted but it's there to decrease the imbalance caused by the offset current of the op amp. Can be ignored for calculations.

$$
\mathrm{
V_{IN}-V_A=I_x\cdot R21 \\
V_{IN}-I_L \cdot R7 = V_A \ \ \ \ (R17 \ is \ ignored) \\
\Rightarrow \frac{I_x}{I_L}= \frac{R7}{R21}
}
$$

So, the circuit generates a current proportional to the load current. The ratio is determined by R7 and R21. To convert this current into a voltage, R30 is placed as a burden resistor (assuming the ADC or the other circuit draws negligible current).

So, the gain for this current-to-voltage converter will be

$$
\mathrm{
V_x=I_x\cdot R30 = (I_L\cdot \frac{R7}{R21})\cdot R30 \\
\Rightarrow \frac{V_x}{I_L}=\frac{R7\cdot R30}{R21} = \frac{1\ V}{1 \ A}
}
$$

The converter generates one Volt at V<sub>X</sub> node per one Amp of output current.

---

This circuit is not a good choice for high-accuracy measurements, because it assumes that the emitter and the collector currents of the output transistor to be equal. Still a good choice for some practical applications. A better option is to use a differential amplifier but the common-mode voltage requirement is a limiting parameter for the op amp (The common-mode voltage of the op amp should be higher than the maximum rail voltage).

Comment: Thank you. Very good explanation. The result is what I had before, but now I have a full explanation.
Application is a current monitor for a wireless power transfer similar to what the bq500211 would have done.

Answer (score 1):

In the circuit below the opamp will try to keep \$V_{out} = V_{fb}\$ (there is no voltage drop across \$R_3\$). That means the voltage across \$R_2\$ is approximately equal to the voltage drop in the shunt (\$R_1\$).

[image]

With the PNP BJT in the active region, the current through \$R_5\$ will be very close to the current through \$R_2\$. Since \$R_5\$ is \$10\times\$ the value of \$R_2\$, so will be the voltage across it:

\$V_{sense} \approx R_5/R_2 \times V_{shunt}\$

This starts to break when the PNP approaches saturation:

[image]

If the measure requirements do not approach the limits (large current values that saturate the transistor and small values that result in small shunt voltages and make the non-ideal opamp characteristics to become relevant) the formula for the voltage gain can be more accurate by using a Darlington pair, which makes the base and collector currents to differ by 4 orders of magnitude or so:

[image]